# perform a specific function for each line read in c++

Tags: c++

I'm want to write a program that will read from a file line by line. For each line read, I will perform a specific function and move to the next line.
What will be a general syntax for this operation in c++

```
int main(){
string line;
string instruction;
string input;
ifstream file("file.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        // perform a function with info from first line
        //den move to second line 


    }
    file.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";




return 0;
```

}

Comment: Learn more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Read the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Your question is off-topic, since too broad.

Comment: Is there something wrong with what you have? It seems to me it would deliver you a line per iteration, which you can use to select your "specific function" (whatever that is).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This doesn't seem to be a compiler type problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're quite there, what you are missing is just the function that would process the line.

```
void processLine(const string& line) {
    cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Then just as you already do:

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
    processLine(line);
}
```